# Oracle Months Between does not work properly

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

Good morning,
I've wrote the following query to get the months difference between a date column (STRT_DT) and a timestamp column (VLD_FRM_TMS) stored in two different tables.
I don't know why it works for some records but does not for others (it calculates one month less)

```
select ID, floor (months_between (cast(a.VLD_FRM_TMS as date), STRT_DT)) as delta
from TABLE_A a
inner join TABLE_B b
on a.ID = b.ID
```

This is an example of record for which the calculation does not work:

```
VLD_FRM_TMS
-----------
28-FEB-21 12.00.00.000000000 AM

STRT_DT
--------
29-OCT-20
```

The formula calculates 3 months instead of 4...

Could anyone help me in locating the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Because the result is `3.xxx` months and your are using `floor`. Try with `round` instead of `floor`.

Comment: Or possibly trunc both values before you calculate the difference, so you're comparing the first day of each month; but it depends what logic you are supposed to be applying.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I actually want the months difference regardless of the specific day of the month. So truncating both dates before comparing should work. I am trying to write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I actually want the months difference regardless of the specific day of the month.

You can [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79) both values to the first of the month [using the `'MM'` format element](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html), and then get the difference between those:

```
months_between (trunc(a.VLD_FRM_TMS, 'MM'), trunc(STRT_DT, 'MM')) as delta
```

That will now always be an integer - i.e. a whole number of months - so you don't need to trunc/floor/round the result.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b41e5a57dcf8499012d696052d664cb9) showing the problem with the old calculation and this version.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the behavior that is described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm):

> If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or **both last days of months**, then the result is always an integer. Otherwise Oracle Database calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month and considers the difference in time components date1 and date2.

(Note:  Highlighting is mine.)

If you run this code:

```
select months_between(date '2021-02-28', date '2020-10-29') as delta
from dual
```

The result is 3.9677.

I suspect that you want some other logic.  However, the question does not specify what logic you actually do want.